# Bash simple search script with individual results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that searches through a file and displays the results.

However there is a problem for example when i search 1 the following results are given:

```
1 B C
11 D E
12 B C
13 D E
```

When i search for `1`,  I only want it to show the `1` not also

```
11 D E
12 B C
13 D E
```

Is this possible?

```
echo "$@" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/.*/g' | xargs -Ifile grep -Ei 'file' text.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried the `-w` option to `grep`?

Comment: You can also use `grep '\b1\b'` to set the word boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the script:

```
grep -o "\b$1\b" <file_name>
```

**Example**

```
vals=1

cat word.txt 
1 B C
11 D E
12 B C
13 D E

grep -o "\b${vals}\b" word.txt 
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
grep -w "1" <filename>
```

Explaination:

```
-w, --word-regexp
             The expression is searched for as a word
```

Output without `w`:

```
grep "1" abc.txt 
1
12
13
111
123
312
412
```

Output with `w`:

```
grep -w "1" abc.txt 
1
```

When content of `abc.txt` is :

```
1
12
13
111
123
312
412
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -w flag with grep command. Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to run this from a script so that i just call the script such as ./script.sh 1 and it does ths. Ive updated the question to show why i use the expression i did.